# Error con angular-generator [Solucion momentanea]

Tags: angularjs, generator

ejecute el generador, instale las dependencias

y al ejecutar `gulp serve` me muestra la pagina de la siguiente manera y con errores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ok, ¿Como lo solucione?:

en .bowerrc cambie la ruta  de bower component por "app/bower_components"

borre la carpeta de bower component que estaba afuera de app y en la terminal escribí `bower install` (todo dentro de la carpeta del proyecto)

en el archivo gulpfile.js aproximando a la linea 146

```
gulp.task('bower', function () {
```

yo cambie:

```
.pipe(gulp.dest(yeoman.app + '/views'));
```

por

```
.pipe(gulp.dest(yeoman.app));
```

Luego aproximado a la linea 165 borre .pipe($.useref({... la primera linea de donde empiezan los .pipe y pegue esto:

```
      return gulp.src(paths.views.main)
   .pipe($.useref({
    searchPath: [yeoman.app, '.tmp'],
    transformPath: function(filePath) {
    return     filePath.replace('/bower_components','/app/bower_components')
    }
}))
```

Después me fui al index ubicado en app para ver si estaban los link(rutas) a los .js y .css de las dependencias instaladas dentro de bower, si no están, en consola  iniciar el servidor de gulp y escribir: `gulp serve` y se deberían cargar las rutas automaticamente y solucionado!

si no háganlo manual, Aquí los dejo.

```
    <!-- bower:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
<!-- endbower -->

    <!-- bower:js -->
  <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
```

y con eso ya debería de visualizarse sin error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando instalen una nueva dependencia debería de ser con `--save` para que las agregue automaticamente al index.

ej: bower install angular-sweetalert --save

saludos y gracias a todos.

Comment: Hola, @HernanHumaña. Por favor, anexa el contenido de `gulpfile.js` en tu pregunta.

Comment: ahi lo he agregado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al parecer es un bug en el generador, según [éste issue](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/1295) en el repositorio de GitHub. El problema según ese mismo hilo es que la tarea `serve` de gulp no mapea la ruta del directorio `bower_components`.

La solución según comentarios en ese hilo sería modificar el `gulpfile.js` para añadir el mapeo estático de los componentes de bower:

```
gulp.task('start:server', function() {
  $.connect.server({
    root:['./.tmp', yeoman.app],
    livereload:true,
    port: 9000,
    middleware:function(connect, opt){
      return [['/bower_components', 
        connect["static"]('./bower_components')]]
    }
  });
});
```

> busque y cambie la carpeta del bower y la puse dentro de app

El directorio `bower_components` no debe ir dentro `./app` debe ir en la raíz.

Comment: es un bug del generador

Comment: Al parecer sí. Se solucionó tu problema?

Comment: @HernanHumaña Considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada si te sirvió

Comment: re-instale de nuevo, agregué ese gulp.task y aun aparece sin la visual y con los tres errores. :/

Answer (score 0):

para que puedas utilizar la carpeta `bower_components` en distinta ubicación y te la tome el gulp, lo mejor que puedes hacer es editar el archivo `.bowerrc` y modificando la siguiente línea de directory con la ruta donde se encuentra `bower_components`.

Por ejemplo:

```
{   "directory": "src/bower_components" }
```